# Grep content out of txt file with regex

Tags: grep

I have a list in a txt file which looks like this.

```
10.9.0.18,tom,34.0.1.2:44395,Thu Apr 18 07:14:20 2019
10.9.0.10,jonas,84.32.45.2:44016,Thu Apr 18 07:16:06 2019
10.9.0.6,philip,23.56.222.3:55202,Thu Apr 18 07:16:06 2019
10.9.0.26,coolguy,12.34.56.7:53316,Thu Apr 18 07:16:06 2019
```

I would like to have a script which provides me with the following output:

> tom jonas philip coolguy

I've been looking into something like this:

`grep -oP "^10.9.0.*,wq$1-\K.*" | cut -d, -f1 | sort`

But I am not quite getting there, getting no output at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting output because `grep` doesn't return anything (you don't need perl regex for this).

You'll need to select the second field too:

```
grep '^10\.9\.0\.' data.txt | cut -d, -f
```

Comment: You don't need an Extended regexp either, a plain old `grep ...` is all you need. You should escape those `.` metachars though because right now they'll match many other strings than just what you want.

Answer (score 3):

1. Extract second field
2. Replace newlines with spaces

```
cat <<EOF |
10.9.0.18,tom,34.0.1.2:44395,Thu Apr 18 07:14:20 2019
10.9.0.10,jonas,84.32.45.2:44016,Thu Apr 18 07:16:06 2019
10.9.0.6,philip,23.56.222.3:55202,Thu Apr 18 07:16:06 2019
10.9.0.26,coolguy,12.34.56.7:53316,Thu Apr 18 07:16:06 2019
EOF
cut -d, -f2 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is an option you could try:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s ", $2} END {print ""}' file.txt
```

The `{printf "%s ", $2` prevents using the default new line and instead uses a space.

The `END {print ""}` is to add a new line after finishing

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer if you want multi-line output:

```
$ awk -F, '/^10\.9\.0/{print $2}' file
tom
jonas
philip
coolguy
```

or this for single:

```
$ awk -F, '/^10\.9\.0/{o=o s $2; s=OFS} END{print o}' file
tom jonas philip coolguy
```

You need to escape the `.`s as they represent any character in a regexp and you don't need to add a `.*` at the end of the regexp as that'll literally match "something or nothing".